# Why is my value not being passed between activities using startActivityForResult() in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity

I have two buttons that, when clicked, I want to pass a 1 or a 2 to the second activity. I used intent.putExtra and intent.getExtra but when I check the variable value in the second activity it is always 0.

**Main Activity**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    oneDownButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.oneDownButton);
    twoDownButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.twoDownButton);
    oneDownButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    twoDownButton.setOnClickListener(this);
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, TheCode.class);


    switch (v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.oneDownButton:
            intent.putExtra("TAKE_DOWN_NUMBER", 1);
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_1);
            break;
        case R.id.twoDownButton:
            intent.putExtra("TAKE_DOWN_NUMBER", 2);
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_1);
            break;
    }

}
```

**TheCode Activity**

```
 @Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();

    // Get the game state sent from the main activity
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    takeDownNumber = intent.getIntExtra("TAKE_DOWN_NUMBER", 0);
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    bugsMessage = "";
    Intent returnIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    returnIntent.putExtra(MainActivity.BUGS_MESSAGE, bugsMessage);
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
    finish();
}
```

Comment: use only `startActivity(intent)` instead of  `startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_1);`

Comment: I need a value passed back from the second to the first as well

Comment: simple create another intent in your activity2 and capture it with getIntent in activity1

Comment: The code looks OK. Try uninstalling the app, rebuilding it and installing it again...

Comment: When I change it to just startActivity(intent), it's still not passing the correct value

Comment: How exactly are you checking the value in the second `Activity`? It doesn't look like you're doing anything with `takeDownNumber` there. Also, do you have a `launchMode` attribute set on the `<activity>` element in the manifest for `TheCode`? If so, what is it?

Comment: Try to access the value of the extras in the OnCreate method, acessing the extras from the bundle argument instead of calling getIntent()

Comment: I copy your code and run on my Android Studio. It works.

Answer (score 1):

you must use onCreate bundle for getting value of extras, use code below:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

oneDownButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.oneDownButton);
twoDownButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.twoDownButton);
oneDownButton.setOnClickListener(this);
twoDownButton.setOnClickListener(this);
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
Intent intent = new Intent(this, TheCode.class);


switch (v.getId())
{
    case R.id.oneDownButton:
        intent.putExtra("TAKE_DOWN_NUMBER", 1);
        startActivity(intent, REQUEST_1);
        break;
    case R.id.twoDownButton:
        intent.putExtra("TAKE_DOWN_NUMBER", 2);
        startActivity(intent, REQUEST_1);
        break;
}

}
```

TheCode Activity:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.secondactivity);      

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle bd = intent.getExtras();       
    if(bd != null)
    {
   //you must use bundle in oncreate method
     takeDownNumber = bd.get("TAKE_DOWN_NUMBER");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your return intent from this:

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
returnIntent.putExtra(MainActivity.BUGS_MESSAGE, bugsMessage);
```

to this:

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putExtra(MainActivity.BUGS_MESSAGE, bugsMessage);
```

You need to create an empty intent and not targeted to MainActivity class.

Comment: his intent work for starting activity, so he must say from and to in his intent.